# WooCommerce: updating cart from checkout page redirects to cart page

Tags: woocommerce

In order to shorten purchase process, my client requested to merge `Cart page` and `Checkout page` so instead of Product page > Cart page > Checkout page I have Product page > Checkout page (with the entire content of `cart.php` appended to it).

Problem: even after setting action attribute of the cart `form` element to `Checkout page` URL, I'm still redirected to `Cart page` when hitting "Update cart". Any idea why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of two things.

1. Update cart action is handled by `WC_Form_Handler` handler class. Location "*includes/class-wc-form-handler.php*". In that the function "update_cart_action()" handles the cart updation. This function at its end executes `wp_safe_redirect` which is being passed with argument `$referer`.
2. If you check in source code of your page, just below the "Update Cart" button are 2 hidden fields, "_wpnonce" and "_wp_http_referer". These 2 fields are rendered because of the function `wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' );`. This is in template `cart.php` after update cart button. More about it [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field).

Value of this "_wp_http_referer" is posted to `WC_Form_Handler` and passed as `$referer`. You will need to remove the "_wp_http_referer" field that is being rendered.

You can do that by replacing the default `wp_nonce_field` function with following.

```
wp_nonce_field( -1, 'woocommerce-cart', false, true ); //previous suggest
-----
//updated suggest below. (explanation follows)
wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', '_wpnonce', false, true );
```

_wpnonce field is required for security, thus 'false' argument in above line disabled rendereing of the referer field only.

Explanation for changed values of first 2 arguments. Function handling cart update verifies the nonce field created in cart. Previous suggest disables the referrer field but also sets the name of nonce field to be `'woocommerce-cart'`. Because of this the nonce verification fails. nonce verification is done by checked the nonce field against its name which is hard-coded in the function as `'_wpnonce'` and the action for the nonce field which is `'woocommerce-cart'`.
The updated suggest/edit creates the nonce field with the name `'_wpnonce'`, which satisfies the verification and also disabled the creation of referrer field.

Thus:

- First argument sets the action name (against which the nonce is verified).
- Second argument sets the name for the nonce field (which matches the
  security check)
- Third argument disables creation of referrer field (which is motive of customization)
- Fourth argument causes the field to 'printed' instead of 'returned'

Hope this helps. Ideally this should work. If it does work, please update your experience here so as to reference for others.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It works but at the same time it doesn't :) When hitting "UPDATE CART" I now stay on Checkout page. However the changes I made in the cart are gone (not processed apparently). Any idea how to resolve this dilemma?

Comment: I have updated the answer and also explained what changes I have made and why. I have checked and confirmed updation of cart in my woocommerce setup with suggested edit. Please try the new edit.