# Woocommerce Cart AJAX not working when cart is loaded with shortcode

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using `[woocommerce_cart]` shortcode to load Cart in hidden absolute full-overlay div which can be opened on any page (it's located in header).

**The problem:** [Cart AJAX](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/cart-ajax/) is not working on any other page except mywebsite.com/cart page.

For example, when I am on my home page, I open my absolute full-overlay div which contains Shopping Cart called by shortcode, and I click on Update Cart button, it does update the cart, but instead of doing it with AJAX, it redirects me to mywebsite.com/cart page.

I figured out how to prevent redirection to /cart page by following this instructions: [WooCommerce: updating cart from checkout page redirects to cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321239/woocommerce-updating-cart-from-checkout-page-redirects-to-cart-page) , but it still reloads the current page instead of using AJAX.

So, the main thing I would like to achieve is to force Cart AJAX on all pages. However, it would also be helpful if someone knows how to prevent redirections after click on Update Cart, Remove Item... BUT only redirections, and let the processes of updating cart, removing items etc. to be completed (so `preventDefault()` is not an option.)

Thanks.

Comment: woocommerce enqueue the **cart.min.js** only in the cart page

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I included cart.min.js on all pages and now it works better. But, the problem now occurring is when I click X to remove product, the item is removed, but after executing this AJAX removal, the shopping cart and "Item removed. Undo?" message are not loaded back. The whole cart simply disappears.

This problem does NOT happen if I am on the /cart page. Also, everything works normally and when I call [woocommerce_cart] without AJAX (when I insert shortcode into WP admin back-end post content).